# How can I create this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print an array that shows a series of [x] when it has information written in it, but how can I save information to that position, being able to ask for the information later, but only showing an 'x' when it has information inside of that position?
...
Thanks!

```
   public class avion2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    char[] vizq= {'V'};
    char[] cizq= {'C'};
    char[] pizq= {'P'};
    char[] vder= {'V'};
    char[] cder= {'C'};
    char[] pder= {'P'};
    for (int i = 0; i < vizq.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("["+ vizq[i]+"]" +"["+cizq[i]+"]" + "[" +pizq[i]+"]"+"\t"+"["+ pder[i]+"]" +"["+cder[i]+"]" + "[" +vder[i]+"]");
    }
    char[] ventanaizq= new char [7];
    char[] centroizq= new char [7];
    char[] pasilloizq= new char [7];
    char[] ventanader= new char [7];
    char[] centroder= new char [7];
    char[] pasilloder= new char [7];
    for (int i = 0; i < ventanaizq.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("["+ ventanaizq[i]+"]" +"["+centroizq[i]+"]"+ "[" +pasilloizq[i]+"]"+"\t"+"["+ pasilloder[i]+"]" +"["+centroder[i]+"]"+ "[" +ventanader[i]+"]");
    }
    }
```

}

These are my arrays. For example. A person occupies the position ventanaizq[2], it must print [x] if the seat is occupied, but , if it is occupied, it must save the information of the person in that spot, that being name and ID. The only thing that prints in console is the [x], the information is hidden until I ask for it.
How can I build another array or modify this one, to do so?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to better explain your problem and show what you have tried so far, where are you stuck, etc. Also a good read is How do I ask a good question? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Currently, it's very hard to understand what you'r asking.

Comment: Please specify. Your question - as of now - is unclear. Also, please provide atleast a little bit of code to show what you've tried thus far. :)

Comment: I assume that you loop through an array and, for each index who is not null, you print the result. What you want is to be able to keep every indexes you previously printed in another array ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways. 
1. Use 2 arrays, one boolean to indicate what indexes are occupied.
2. Use an array of objects, where the object returns what you want unless especially called for something else.

Edit:
I have no clue what your code i trying to do, but this might help get started.

```
public class Arrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person[][] seats = new Person[10][10];

    seats[4][5] = new Person();
    seats[4][5].age = 45;
    seats[4][5].name = "Thomas";

    System.out.println(seats[4][5]);
    System.out.println(seats[4][5].getAge());

}

static class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + age;
    }
}
```